# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 7 column 1 (char 6) in three different files

Tags: python, json

I am trying to load a json file from this link:

https://github.com/annexare/Countries/tree/master/data

```py
f = open ('countries.json')
data = json.load(f)
```

I received the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-271-3c5bb9db18ae> in <module>
      1 f = open ('countries.json')
----> 2 data = json.load(f)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py in load(fp, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    294         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
    295         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,
--> 296         parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    297 
    298 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 7 column 1 (char 6)**
```

Here are the first few lines of the JSON file:

```
{
  "AD": {
    "name": "Andorra",
    "native": "Andorra",
    "phone": "376",
    "continent": "EU",
    "capital": "Andorra la Vella",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "languages": [
      "ca"
    ]
  },
```

If you have a recommendation, please let me know.

Comment: We need to see what is in each of these file—or at least the beginnings of them all (since the error occurs on line 7). The traceback doesn't show the data that's being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

So the major issue is the encoding and changing  your code to this

```py
import json
f = open(file='countries.json',mode='rb')
contents = f.read()
data = json.loads(contents)
```

should solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

See below (it works with no issues)

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/annexare/Countries/master/data/countries.json')
if r.status_code == 200:
    data = r.json()
    print(data)
r = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/annexare/Countries/master/data/languages.json')
if r.status_code == 200:
    data = r.json()
    print(data)
```

Comment: Hello balderman, if you change the link by '​https://github.com/annexare/Countries/blob/master/data/languages.json'  show a similar error.

Comment: @Ronny I checked the languages as well. It works with no issues. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your support Balderman. I found a solution. the best way to get the right information was to open the direct link in Chrome navigator. Then I copy the text information and I did paste it into a **Google JSON Editor** application. After, I downloaded the file fixed.

Comment: @Ronny Did you check my code? I think it works with the editing you did.

Answer (score -1):

The code you posted is definitely ok. One of potential issues it can be - maybe you tried to use `json.load(f)` multiple times on same file stream (`f`). In order to check if that's the issue please try `data = json.load(open('countries.json'))`.
That way, file stream will be always recreated